# how to split time into hours?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains how many seconds a user has spent on a certain webpage(task) as follows:

```
UserID  Page1   Page2   Page3 ....
24      2789    2375    574 
39      3745    3800    4567
35      100     300     1005
.
.
.
```

I want to have these seconds split into hours as follows so I can know on which page every user was during a certain hour of his/her navigation of the site:

```
UserID  Hour1     Hour2     Hour3  ....
24      Page1     Page1     Page2 
39      Page1     Page2     Page3
35      Page1     Page1     Page1
.
.
.
```

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution essentials:

*(Complete code at the end of the answer)*

```
# reshape
dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['UserID'], value_vars=df.columns[1:])

# rename
dfm.columns = ['UserID', 'variable', 'hour']

# crosstab into final form
df_ct = pd.crosstab(dfm['UserID'],dfm['hour'],dfm['variable'],aggfunc='last')
```

#### Output

```
hour        1      2      3      4
UserID                            
24      Page1  Page3    NaN    NaN
35      Page3    NaN    NaN    NaN
39        NaN  Page1  Page2  Page3
```

#### Some details

I ran into a similar challenge recently and also got a few good suggestions on [How to handle ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries using df.pivot or pd.pivot_table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974776/how-to-handle-valueerror-index-contains-duplicate-entries-using-df-pivot-or-pd) that should prove useful here as well. In your particular case I would approach it this way:

1. Obtain accumulated time with [`df.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html),
2. convert seconds to hours wtih `df / (60*60)`,
3. focus on complete hours using integers with `df.astype(int)`,
4. reshape your `df` for easier calculatins with [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), and then
5. obtain final form with [`pd.crosstab()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

#### Result 1:

```
hour        0      1      2      3
UserID                            
24      Page1  Page3    NaN    NaN
35      Page3    NaN    NaN    NaN
39        NaN  Page1  Page2  Page3
```

And then it's up to you how you would like to present the information. As it now stands, `User 24` finished `Page1 before an hour had passed`, and finished `Page2 and Page3` before the start of the second hour. It might feel more natural to start the hours at `1`. In that case, just include

```
df = df + 1
```

in the initial steps to get:

#### Restult 2: Hours start at `1`

```
hour        1      2      3      4
UserID                            
24      Page1  Page3    NaN    NaN
35      Page3    NaN    NaN    NaN
39        NaN  Page1  Page2  Page3
```

And now it's all just a question how to handle the `NaNs`. You can include `.fill()` in:

```
d.crosstab(dfm['UserID'],dfm['hour'],dfm['variable'],aggfunc='last')#.ffill(axis=1)
```

And get:

#### Result 3: Taking care of `NaNs`

```
hour        1      2      3      4
UserID                            
24      Page1  Page3  Page3  Page3
35      Page3  Page3  Page3  Page3
39        NaN  Page1  Page2  Page3
```

`User 39` still has a `NaN` for `'Hour1`, but I'll wait for your feedback on what you'd like to do with that one.

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd

# data
df_i = pd.DataFrame({'UserID': {0: 24, 1: 39, 2: 35},
                     'Page1': {0: 2789, 1: 3745, 2: 100},
                     'Page2': {0: 2375, 1: 3800, 2: 300},
                     'Page3': {0: 574, 1: 4567, 2: 1005}}).set_index('UserID')

# time conversion
df = df_i.cumsum(axis = 1)
df = df / (60*60)
df = df.astype(int)
df = df + 1
df = df.reset_index()

# reshape
dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['UserID'], value_vars=df.columns[1:])

# rename
dfm.columns = ['UserID', 'variable', 'hour']

# crosstab into final form
df_ct = pd.crosstab(dfm['UserID'],dfm['hour'],dfm['variable'],aggfunc='last').ffill(axis=1)
df_ct
# df
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want the final output columns to be the actual hours or just show the original data in hourly form? If the latter this should work

```
# Melt down DataFrame
df = df.melt(id_vars='UserID',var_name='Page',value_name='Seconds')

  UserID Page   Seconds
0   24  Page1   2789
1   39  Page1   3745
2   35  Page1   100
3   24  Page2   2375
4   39  Page2   3800
5   35  Page2   300
6   24  Page3   574
7   39  Page3   4567
8   35  Page3   1005

# Create column of Seconds converted to Hours
df['Hours'] = df['Seconds'] / 60

# Convert float to int data type
df['Hours'] = df['Hours'].astype(int)

UserID  Page    Seconds Hours
0   24  Page1   2789    46
1   39  Page1   3745    62
2   35  Page1   100     1
3   24  Page2   2375    39
4   39  Page2   3800    63
5   35  Page2   300     5
6   24  Page3   574     9
7   39  Page3   4567    76
8   35  Page3   1005    16

# Create new DataFrame of pivoted df DataFrame
df_hrs = df.pivot_table(index=['UserID'],columns=['Page'], values='Hours')

# Reset index to flatten DataFrame
df_hrs.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Change column name attribute
df_hrs.columns.rename('',inplace=True)

 UserID Page1   Page2   Page3
0   24   46     39      9
1   35   1      5       16
2   39   62     63      76
```

Comment: thank you but this doesn't work. I want to know which page was the user on during the first hour, second hour, third hour and so on.

Comment: @MohammadAlshehri where is the column with the start and stop time for when the user got on and off each page? Your question only provided what appears to be a duration of how long the user was on the page in seconds.

Comment: I don't have the time stamp for when a user got on and off each page, I only know how long they spent on each page in seconds.