# How to handle ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries using df.pivot or pd.pivot_table?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a table showing the accumulated number of hours (`dataframe values`) different specialists  (`ID`) have taken to complete a sequence of four tasks `['Task1, 'Tas2', 'Task3, 'Tas4']` like this:

#### Input:

```
    ID  Task1   Task2   Task3   Task4
0   10      1       3       4       6
1   11      1       3       4       5
2   12      1       3       4       6
```

Now I'd like to reshape that dataframe so that I can easily find out which task each specialist was working on after 1 hour, 2 hours, and so on. So the desired output looks like this:

#### Desired output:

```
value   1       3       4       5       6
ID                  
10  Task1   Task2   Task3   Task3   Task4
11  Task1   Task2   Task3   Task4   Task4
12  Task1   Task2   Task3   Task3   Task4
```

With this particular dataframe, I've managed to produce the desired output using `pd.melt()`, `pd.pivot()` and `pd.fillna()` like this (complete snippet with sample data further down):

#### What I have tried:

```
df = pd.melt(df1, id_vars=['ID'], value_vars=df1.columns[1:])
df = df.pivot(index='ID', columns = 'value', values = 'variable')
df = df.fillna(method = 'ffill', axis = 1)
```

The problem is that this approach is not very robust, in that it can easily collapse with a dataset that would render (I think) duplicate column names. Here's an example where that happens by just changing `Task3` for `ID=0` from `5 to 4`:

#### Code 1

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({   'ID': {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12},
                   'Task1': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
                   'Task2': {0: 4, 1: 3, 2: 3},
                   'Task3': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4},
                   'Task4': {0: 6, 1: 5, 2: 6}})

df = pd.melt(df1, id_vars=['ID'], value_vars=df1.columns[1:])
df = df.pivot(index='ID', columns = 'value', values = 'variable')
df = df.fillna(method = 'ffill', axis = 1)
df
```

#### Code 1 - Error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

And according to [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), [pd.pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) is a:

> generalization of pivot that can handle duplicate values for one index/column pair.

So I was hoping that `pd.pivot_table()` would be better suited for this case. Alas, this triggers:

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Does anyone know if it's at all possible to obtain a robust way of handling these errors? Am I perhaps only using `pd.pivot_table()` the wrong way? I've also tried to include `aggfunc=None`.

I'm at a loss here, so *any* suggestions would be great! Although I'm *hoping* for an approach with `df.pivot` or `pd.pivot_table` and / or the shortest approach possible.

#### Complete working code example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({   'ID': {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12},
                   'Task1': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
                   'Task2': {0: 4, 1: 3, 2: 3},
                   'Task3': {0: 5, 1: 4, 2: 4},
                   'Task4': {0: 6, 1: 5, 2: 6}})

df = pd.melt(df1, id_vars=['ID'], value_vars=df1.columns[1:])
df = df.pivot(index='ID', columns = 'value', values = 'variable')
df = df.fillna(method = 'ffill', axis = 1)
df
```

#### Complete example where both `df.pivot` and `pd.pivot_table` fail:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({   'ID': {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12},
                   'Task1': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
                   'Task2': {0: 4, 1: 3, 2: 3},
                   'Task3': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4},
                   'Task4': {0: 6, 1: 5, 2: 6}})

df = pd.melt(df1, id_vars=['ID'], value_vars=df1.columns[1:])
# df = df.pivot(index='ID', columns = 'value', values = 'variable')

df = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns = 'value', values = 'variable')
df = df.fillna(method = 'ffill', axis = 1)
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this also using pd.crosstab:

```
dfm = df.melt('ID', value_name='val')
df_out = pd.crosstab(dfm['ID'],dfm['val'],dfm['variable'],aggfunc='first').ffill(axis=1)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
val      1      3      4      5      6
ID                                    
10   Task1  Task1  Task2  Task2  Task4
11   Task1  Task2  Task3  Task4  Task4
12   Task1  Task2  Task3  Task3  Task4
```

Or changing the aggfunc to 'last':

```
dfm = df.melt('ID', value_name='val')
df_out = pd.crosstab(dfm['ID'],dfm['val'],dfm['variable'],aggfunc='last').ffill(axis=1)
df_out
```

Output:

```
val      1      3      4      5      6
ID                                    
10   Task1  Task1  Task3  Task3  Task4
11   Task1  Task2  Task3  Task4  Task4
12   Task1  Task2  Task3  Task3  Task4
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work when you try it with ```df1``` in the last code block in the question.

Comment: @PSK  It worked on all the dfs in this question.

Comment: What is wrong with the output?  I am not getting any errors.

Comment: For ```df1``` in the last code block in the question, for ```ID``` 10 at ```val``` 4 and 5, shouldn't it have ```Task3``` and not ```Task2```?

Comment: What if we change the aggfunc to last instead of first?  Is tha correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. According to me at least!

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank you for a very elegant suggestion!

Comment: @vestland You're welcome.  Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that this is not the best way to do this but it is one way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12},
                   'Task1': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
                   'Task2': {0: 4, 1: 3, 2: 3},
                   'Task3': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4},
                   'Task4': {0: 6, 1: 5, 2: 6}})

df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['ID'], value_vars=df.columns[1:])
df1['value'] = df1['value'].astype(int)
df1.set_index(['ID','value'], inplace=True)

df_max_val = df.set_index('ID').max().max()
ids = df['ID'].tolist()*df_max_val
values = list(np.array([[i]*len(set(ids)) for i in range(1, df_max_val+1)]).flatten())
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':ids,
                    'value':values})
df2.set_index(['ID','value'], inplace=True)

df3 = df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
df3 = df3.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','value'], keep='last')
df3 = pd.concat([df3[df3['ID']==i].fillna(method='ffill') for i in df3['ID'].unique()])
df3 = df3.pivot(index='ID', columns='value', values='variable')
```

Comment: This seems to work fine! Thank you for your suggestion. You have my upvote, but since I'm hoping for a shorter approach I'll wait a few days before I mark your suggestion as the accepted answer as well.